# Linux IntelliJ Chrome WebDriverManager "chrome (or any other browser) failed to start"

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I have a problem with WebDriverManager.

If I specify path to the downloaded chromedriver I get this [link](https://pastebin.com/mKA31YEz)

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/ja/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/73.0.3683.20/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Edit 1. If I have installed chrome it works.

Edit 2. Problem occurs only when browser I want to test on isn't installed.

Edit 3. (browser)Driver downloaded by WebDriverManageris working if I run it through terminal (Linux terminal and IntelliJ terminal).

Edit 4. Turns out I'm just stupid. I thought WebDriverManager let you run tests on browsers you dont have installed. That would be pretty awesome though...

Comment: @Boni García please help :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using an old version of WebDriverManager. Try with the latest, since as of WebDriverManager 3.x the downloaded version of chromedriver is not the latest by default, but the proper version for your Chrome browser.

Comment: I am using 3.3.0 version

Comment: Pom file: https://pastebin.com/t3EFBkxi
Test: https://pastebin.com/0a44G9sZ

Comment: Which is your Chrome version?

Comment: Or just whole project (8kb zip): https://www57.zippyshare.com/v/luiY9MWR/file.html

Comment: ok, maybe i'm just confused, is your plugin supposed to download needed binaries for a test when you dont have a browser installed, so when you run test on 5 browsers you dont need to download and install all of them?

Comment: Chrome must be installed beforehand if you plan to control it with WebDriver. WebDriverManager downloads chromedriver, which is required to control Chrome from WebDriver.

Comment: o oooo, my friend had mislead me, im so sorry